# Image doesn't fit inside div

Tags: css, html

I am finding it hard to fit an image inside a Div that contain a text. Everytime I try to get it to fit inside the boundaries of the super div, it simply goes out of bounds regardless of what I use from the css side. can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```css
.justRight {
  float: right;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  background-image: url(https://internal.bs.fb.ac.uk/modules/2017- 
 18/bsl/css/sign_language.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.jas {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px outset blue;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-top: 40px solid blue;
  border-right: 2px outset blue;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 96.3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="jas">
  <h1>Sign Language</h1>
  <div class="justRight">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What image do you mean? the background?

Comment: I don't want it to be the background of the master div, I want it to be aligned with the text on the right of the master div

Comment: share the image please; img link seems to be broken.

Comment: I think it is because it is linked to to a uni server, to which you would have to be logged in in order to access the image. you can use any image you want(if you have any). I doesn't seem to matter on my end

Answer (score 0):

By saying `height: 80px` to parent (.jas), you are restricting the parent div's height to 80px. So it wont go beyond. So remove height of parent(.jas). Set a height to the child instead(.justRight).

Not sure why you used `float: right` value to the child(.justRight). Please remove if it is unnecessary.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/johnsackson/pen/KRdvMQ

```
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   .justRight {
      height: 100px;
      max-width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      background: url(https://placehold.it/1920x200) 0 0 no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }

    .jas {
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px outset blue;
      /* position: absolute;  */ /* use if only needed */
      margin: 10px 0;
      border-top: 40px solid blue;
      border-right: 2px outset blue;
      padding: 0 10px;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that the `h1` tag is on position: relative. Changing it would solve your issues.

```
h1 {position: absolute}
```